# osrm storing polyline string efficiently

Tags: php, mysql, osrm

Hi there I am using `OSRM` project APIs to generate a route for some points I have such a case that `the generated polyline string is too long for a column of type "text" in the MYSQL database`.
how can I use OSRM to generate the polyline string more efficiently and store it in MYSQL database?